# The internal localhost URL of ionic app on iOS to

Tags: angular, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic/Angular app that connect to AWS S3 to upload pictures (using aws-sdk v2). It works well on web and Android. Sadly on iOS I can't upload pictures and get NetworkingError: Network Failure.

I already added every possible CORS :
"AllowedOrigins": "*"
"AllowedHeaders": "*"

The only difference I see is that in web it run with URL : http://localhost:8100
In Android : http://localhost
In iOS : capacitor://localhost

This is maybe the issue of the problem. Is there a way to make the iOS version run under "http://" and not "capacitor://" ? this will maybe solve my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I got it, I change in capacitor.config.ts CapacitorHttp -> enabled to false :

webDir: 'www',
"plugins": {
"CapacitorHttp": {
"enabled": **false**
}
}

request is now ok.